# Escape quotes in shell

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

What am I doing wrong, tried everything

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='delete'

while read p; do 
    jq '\'if .tweet | test('\"$p\"'; "i") then . |= . + {vendor: '\"$p\"'} else empty end\' sfilter.json
done < $filename
```

was following this example

```
echo $'\'single quote phrase\' "double quote phrase"'
'single quote phrase' "double quote phrase"
```

Comment: You cannot escape single quotes in single quotes. `$'...'` are not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if escaping a single quote, before the slash `\` a single quote should not be required

an example,

`echo \$pd`

the result should be `$pd` because you escaped the `$` character